# Prevent concurrent execution

Tags: concurrency, rust, async-await, hyper

I want to prevent concurrent execution of a function called asynchronously.
The function gets called from a hyper service and two connections should lead to one waiting until the other function call is done. I thought implementing a Future to block execution until other threads / connections are done will solve the issue. Coming to my problem I store the Futures in a `Mutex<HashMap<i64, LockFut>>` but when I lock the mutex to get and await the LockFut it obviously complains about the MutexGuard not being send. I don't know how to work around this or if my way is just bad.

```
    |
132 |         let mut locks = LOCKS.lock().unwrap();
    |             --------- has type `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, std::collections::HashMap<i64, hoster::hoster::LockFut>>`
...
136 |         lock.await;
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^ await occurs here, with `mut locks` maybe used later
137 |     }
    |     - `mut locks` is later dropped here
```

This is my future implementation

```
lazy_static! {
   static ref LOCKS: Mutex<HashMap<i64, LockFut>> = Mutex::new(HashMap::new());
}

struct LockState {
    waker: Option<Waker>,
    locked: bool
}

struct LockFut {
    state: Arc<Mutex<LockState>>
}

impl Future for LockFut {
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let mut state = self.state.lock().unwrap();
        match state.locked {
            false => {
                Poll::Ready(())
            },
            true => {
                state.waker = Some(cx.waker().clone());
                Poll::Pending
            }
        }
    }
}

impl LockFut {
    fn new() -> LockFut {
        LockFut {
            state: Arc::new(Mutex::new(LockState {
                locked: false,
                waker: None
            }))
        }
    }

    pub fn release_lock(&mut self) {
        let mut state = self.state.lock().unwrap();
        state.locked = false;
        if let Some(waker) = state.waker.take() {
            waker.wake();
        }
    }

    pub async fn lock<'a>(id: i64) {
        let mut locks = LOCKS.lock().unwrap();
        // Wait for existing lock to be unlocked or create a new lock
        let lock = locks.entry(id).or_insert(LockFut::new());
        // Wait for the potential lock to be released
        lock.await;
    }

    pub fn unlock(id: i64) {
        match LOCKS.lock().unwrap().get_mut(&id) {
            Some(lock) => lock.release_lock(),
            None => warn!("No lock found for: {}", id)
        };
    }
}
```

And this is how I call it

```
async fn is_concurrent(id: i64) {
  should_not_be_concurrent().await;
}

async fn should_not_be_concurrent(id: i64) {
  LockFut::lock(id).await;
  // Do crazy stuff
  LockFut::unlock(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guard from standard `Mutex` is `!Send` indeed, so it cannot be carried between the `await`-s. For that task usually asynchronous mutexes are good thing to consider. There's one in [`futures`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/lock/struct.Mutex.html) and also there's a [stand-alone crate](https://crates.io/crates/async_mutex). Their guards are `Send` and the problem should be resolved at this point.

But I'd like to go further and say that `LockFut` solves the exact same problem as async Mutex does. Thus for this particular example code can be significantly simplified to the following ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28120c359173840f02a25ead74f9de30)):

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex as StdMutex;
use futures::lock::Mutex;

#[derive(Default)]
struct State { .. }

type SharedState = Arc<Mutex<State>>;

lazy_static! {
   static ref LOCKS: StdMutex<HashMap<i64, SharedState>> = Default::default();
}

fn acquire_state<'a>(id: i64) -> SharedState {
    Arc::clone(&LOCKS.lock().unwrap().entry(id).or_default())
}


// Acquiring is straightforward:
let mut state = acquire_state(0).lock().await;


// or with your functions:
async fn is_concurrent(id: i64) {
    should_not_be_concurrent(id).await;
}

async fn should_not_be_concurrent(id: i64) {
    let mut state = acquire_state(id).lock().await;
    // Do crazy stuff

    // As a bonus there's no need in manual unlocking here
    // since `drop(state)` unlocks the mutex. 
}
```

Also, you may find helpful [this](https://kitsu.me/posts/2020_06_01_mutex_in_async_world) blog post regarding mutexes in async code.

Comment: Thank you very much <3. The AsyncMutex was exactly what I was searchiinng for and the Article you posted helped me to understand the options. Awesome